# return value from recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, return-value

I have a recursive method that i would like to return a value from when a specific if statement returns true (which it always does)

```
    if (compactArray != null) {
            if (arrayCount == (compactArray[0].length - 1)) {
                return compactArray;//i want to return here
            }
        }
```

But Java wont let me return from the if, and throws a warning that i need to add a return value.

What does one do? The full method is as follows

```
public String[][] diXmlRecursiveRead(Iterator<Element> list, String[] columnNames, String[][] compactArray,
        Integer arrayCount) {
    Element element = null;
    String[] columns = null;

    while (list.hasNext()) {
        element = list.next();

        // Assign data to the two dimensional array, starting from position
        // 1 in the length to not overwrite the column names.
        // This is also where i would print the column name plus its
        // attribute value if i was printing to console.
        if (columnNames != null) {
            for (int a = 0; a < columnNames.length; a++) {
                compactArray[a][arrayCount] = element.getAttributeValue(columnNames[a]);
            }
        }

        // Find the element that contains the columns="" information
        if (element.getAttributeValue("columns") != null) {
            // reset the array count, since we are processing a new
            // columns="" section
            arrayCount = 1;

            columns = element.getAttributeValue("columns").toString().split(",");

            // set width size +1 to make room for the column names
            // (columnNames + data +1)
            compactArray = new String[columns.length][element.getChildren().size() + 1];

            // Set the EVE column names in the first column of the two
            // dimensional array
            for (int a = 0; a < columns.length; a++) {
                compactArray[a][0] = columns[a];
            }
        }

        // After added the last value to the two dimensional array return the
        // array[][]
        if (compactArray != null) {
            if (arrayCount == (compactArray[0].length - 1)) {
                return compactArray;//i want to return here and not at the end!
            }
        }

        // Method calls itself with a new level of the child
        diXmlRecursiveRead(element.getChildren().iterator(), columns, compactArray, arrayCount++);
    }
    //Java want me to return here!!
}
```

Comment: Why not add a return statement at the end?

Comment: "But Java wont let me return from the if" - I'm sure it will. But it also wants you to return from the end of the method - or throw an exception, or some other way of making sure it can never reach the end of the method without returning a value.

Comment: `I have a recursive method that i would like to return a value from when a specific if statement returns true (which it always does)`

What's the point of a conditional if it is always true?

Comment: [quote]Why not add a return statement at the end?[/quote]
Because than it dosent return the fully buildt array

[quote]What's the point of a conditional if it is always true? [/quote]
To wait for a condition to be meet before making something true, as the array being fully buildt.

Comment: The Array will have to be build while doing recursions. Of course this may twist your head i'm sure it does twist mine. ;) - Maybe start with a simpler example using an Array of primitives to get recursion to work first. Also there might be data structures easier to use than arrays for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

look at that example:

```
static int count = 0;
private static boolean foo() {
    if (count == 5) {
        return true;
    }
    count ++;
    return foo();
}
```

note that the recursive call is called with the 'return' statement. 
Think about the stack that is being build when you execute a recursive method. at some point all methods need to start returning a value up the stack.

Comment: So if my method runs 19 times it will need to return 19 values?

Comment: no. the actual return only happens once. but each step should have a return statement for the previous step in the recursion.
when a method return a value the method that called it (in that case the same method) will need to do something with the value, and then return something to the calling method etc.. so in your case the return value of the recursive call should also be the value that is returned. hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the info +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass through the String[][] compactArray parameter and return that. This is the result of your method that will be returned at the end.

Returning starts when the deepest level of recursion is done. Then everything is passed through till the first call of your method.

Added some code:

```
    package recursion;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.xml.bind.Element;

class Recursionat0r {

    static private int threshhold = 3;

    public static void main(String[] grmlZ) {

        Recursionat0r recursionat0r = new Recursionat0r();

        String[] columnNames = { "hello", "world" };

        String[][] compactArray = new String[4][10]; // would recommend
                                                        // ArrayList here

        compactArray = recursionat0r.diXmlRecursiveRead(null, columnNames, compactArray, 0);

        recursionat0r.printCompactArray(compactArray);

    }

    public String[][] diXmlRecursiveRead(Iterator<Element> list, String[] columnNames, String[][] compactArray,
            Integer arrayCount) {

        String[] columns = columnNames;

        // append stuff to array
        // compactArray[a][arrayCount] =
        compactArray[arrayCount] = columnNames;

        // Method calls itself with a new level of the child
        // this is a _recursion step_
        // OR
        // Method returns the compactArray!
        // this is the _recursion ancor_
        if (arrayCount < threshhold) {

            System.out.println("returning diXmlRecursiveRead");

            return diXmlRecursiveRead(null, columns, compactArray, ++arrayCount);//increment arrayCount BEFORE passing ;) - else it gives stackoverflow (haha)

            // Java want me to return here!!
        } else {
            System.out.println("returning the compactArray");
            // _recursion anchor_
            return compactArray; // this marks the end of the recursion
            // values start to be passed back from here
            // you might want to specify another condition for the anchor to be
            // thrown ;)
        }
    }

    public void printCompactArray(String[][] compactArray){
        for(int count = 0; count < compactArray.length; count++){
            for(int inside=0; inside < compactArray[0].length; inside++) //warning assuming all Arrays in compactArray have the same length
            System.out.println(compactArray[count][inside]);
        }
    }

}
```

This yields:

returning diXmlRecursiveRead

returning diXmlRecursiveRead

returning diXmlRecursiveRead

returning the compactArray

hello

world

hello

world

hello

world

hello

world

Hope this helps ^^-d

Comment: @Cristian Matthias Ambæk added working example, i did not use JDOM Elements though but it shows the principle by filling an array (compactArray) recursively.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to add a default return value to your method.
The compiler needs to know wich value to return when your 'if' test fails.

Comment: If i just add a return statement at the end, the first thing returned is a null, than throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException. Because the array i (really) want to return hasnt been buildt. Which is why i would like to use a if statement that checks when the array is fully buildt and than return it

Comment: You should review your logic.

Comment: Methods with "non void" return always have to return something by default.

Comment: If someone passes a empty "list", the executer will not enter the 'while' statement. You need to tell the compiler what it must do in this situation.

Comment: >You should review your logic
Any suggestions? Im non a Java pro by any means.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add a return value at the end, just to make the compiler relax. This happens because, if the "if" clause is false, then you return nothing from this function. I guess this is a base case return, right?

Comment: If i just add a return statement at the end, the first thing returned is a null, than throwing a java.lang.NullPointerException. Because the array i (really) want to return hasnt been buildt. Which is why i would like to use a if statement that checks when the array is fully buildt and than return it

Comment: it should be something like
return diXmlRecursiveRead(element.getChildren().iterator(), columns, compactArray, arrayCount++);

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
    // Method calls itself with a new level of the child
    diXmlRecursiveRead(element.getChildren().iterator(), columns, compactArray, arrayCount++);
```

to

```
    // Method calls itself with a new level of the child
    return diXmlRecursiveRead(element.getChildren().iterator(), columns, compactArray, arrayCount++);
```

Note the added `return di...`.

If a method returns a value then ALL routes through the code must return something. In your case only the deepest level of recursion will return something. All the others would just throw away the value discovered.

Comment: if i add the return as you suggest without a default return statement i get the error.

If i add the return as you suggest and a default return statement (return compactArray;) to get past the error the entire method is only run once.and i return null

Comment: @CristianMatthiasAmbæk You are right - so you need to ask yourself
1. What should you return if the list is empty?
2. What to return if more than one entry in the list results in a match.

Comment: Will delete this answer soon as it does not answer the question - when OP has had a chance to read my comment above.